# ProxyPassMatch or rewrite for query string not working apache

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to match if "ajax" is present in the query string and if so ignore it, but its not working in any way. Any idea?

```
   #ProxyPassMatch  ^/(.*ajax.*)$ !

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*ajax.*$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /is_ajaxx [P]
   ProxyPass /is_ajaxx !
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems neither REQUEST_URI or ProxyPassMatch have a query string knowledge, thus we need to use %{QUERY_STRING} instead and then a match should happen